# Cannot get the entire column in a MSI table! Only get first Value of column

Tags: python, sql, database, windows-installer, fetch

I need to get all the strings from the Target column of an MSI's shortcut table. I get the first value of the column, but I cannot get the rest. I used orca to make sure there were other values and the msi files each have two.

Here is my code to get it:

```
def verify(self):
    self.db = msilib.OpenDatabase(str(self.msi_file),msilib.MSIDBOPEN_TRANSACT)
    self.getColumnNames()

def getColumnNames(self):
    view = self.db.OpenView("SELECT Target FROM Shortcut ")
    view.Execute(None)
    print view.GetColumnInfo(msilib.MSICOLINFO_NAMES)
    record = view.Fetch()
    print record.GetFieldCount()
    self.value = record.GetString(1)
    print record.GetString(1)
```

What do I have wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

You need a while record is not null loop to process all your rows. See the following help topic for more information:

[View.Fetch method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372509%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)